# PHP / MySQL: synchronize two fields in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

I need to synchronize two different booking calendars, beacause both calendars book the same room (or the same event).

So, if a client book a day (and hours) in calendar_01, this value (booked day and hours) will be automatically updated in calendars_02 (and vice versa).

It's important to update (and rewrite the new value) in order of the last time (most recent booking) without a continuous loop.

**MySql DB**

I'm using a plugin for this and in "calendars" database there is a table called "days", in this table I can see this:

```
+--------------+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| unique_key   | calendar_id | day        | year | data                                                     |
+--------------+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 1_2014-08-20 | 1           | 2014-08-20 | 2014 | available h10-12; booked h12-14; in pending h14-16;      |
| 2_2014-08-20 | 2           | 2014-08-20 | 2014 | available h 10 - 12; available h12-14; available h14-16; |
| 1_2014-08-21 | 1           | 2014-08-21 | 2014 | available h10-12; available-14; available h14-16;        |
| 2_2014-08-21 | 2           | 2014-08-21 | 2014 | booked h10-12; booked h12-14; in pending h14-16;         |
+--------------+-------------+------------+------+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Simplification: column "data" contains the values (TEXT type) that record every rebooking, so:

```
+--------------+-------------+------------+------+--------------+
| unique_key   | calendar_id | day        | year | data         |
+--------------+-------------+------------+------+--------------+
| 1_2014-08-20 | 1           | 2014-08-20 | 2014 | text value A |
| 2_2014-08-20 | 2           | 2014-08-20 | 2014 | text value B |
| 1_2014-08-21 | 1           | 2014-08-21 | 2014 | text value C |
| 2_2014-08-21 | 2           | 2014-08-21 | 2014 | text value D |
+--------------+-------------+------------+------+--------------+
```

I need to update the values of the same column "data", like this:

```
+--------------+-------------+------------+------+--------------+
| unique_key   | calendar_id | day        | year | data         |
+--------------+-------------+------------+------+--------------+
| 1_2014-08-20 | 1           | 2014-08-20 | 2014 | text value A |
| 2_2014-08-20 | 2           | 2014-08-20 | 2014 | text value A |
| 1_2014-08-21 | 1           | 2014-08-21 | 2014 | text value D |
| 2_2014-08-21 | 2           | 2014-08-21 | 2014 | text value D |
| 1_2014-08-22 | 1           | 2014-08-22 | 2014 | text value X |
| 2_2014-08-22 | 2           | 2014-08-22 | 2014 | text value X |
| 1_2014-08-23 | 1           | 2014-08-23 | 2014 | text value Y |
| 2_2014-08-23 | 2           | 2014-08-23 | 2014 | text value Y |
+--------------+-------------+------------+------+--------------+
```

Many thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't know who designed the data model for this purpose, but it's absolutely horrible and problems are arising because, well, it's horrible. :/

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do. Also, you shouldn't store redundant data. Drop the column year, you can get this information with the `year()` function used on your `day` column. Don't name columns like keywords - `day` is a function like year. Your unique key is a combination of `calendar_id` and `day`. Either you make those two columns the unique key and drop the `unique_key` column (also a suboptimal name for a column) or just use an auto_increment column. And the biggest problem: Never store comma separated values in one column! Read about normalization.

Comment: @N.B. I purchased this plugin. :(
However it means a good plugin...ehm...maybe. :/

Comment: @francyPants I'd just like to duplicate values of two rows, when one value changes, the other value must change. ;) But I don't understand all your comment, is there a solution? Is it difficult? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advice against syncing/Data Replication. You'd need to run a deamon 24/7, the risk of running into issues is much higher, it's also less eficient since It has to keep checking for new data in both tables which also means a delay for people to see their new bookings on the site. And it not so easy to debug when something does go wrong with the deamon.

The following solution is much easier to debug, more efficient. I would suggest you write abstract CRUD code for the data: Create, Read, Update and Delete. Create and Update are probably the ones you're most interested in, what you would do is something like this:

```
<?php
function create($id, $data)
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data['data']);
    mysqL_query("INSERT INTO calendars (unique_key,data) VALUES('".$id."','".$data."')");
    mysqL_query("INSERT INTO days (unique_key,data) VALUES('".$id."','".$data."')");
}
function update($id, $data)
{
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data['data']);
    mysqL_query("UPDATE calendars SET data = '".$data."' WHERE unique_key = '".$id."'");
    mysqL_query("UPDATE days SET data = '".$data."' WHERE unique_key = '".$id."'");
}
create('1_2014-08-20', array(
    'data' => 'data here'
));
update('1_2014-08-20', array(
    'data' => 'data here'
));
```

This is as simple as passing data into it. If you ever modify the SQL structure you can create a new abstraction set of functions/classes that follows the new database structure and it's as easy as swapping out an include.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I'm not sure to be able for this edit, but I was looking for something like this, so I'll try it. :) 
P.S. I'd like to give you a 1pt, but I'haven't permission. :/ 
Thank you again!

Comment: Don't worry about it, it's no problem at all. You're welcome.

Comment: Nothing, I can't resolve. Your code display two errors in line create('1_2014-08-20', [ and update('1_2014-08-20', [

Comment: It's a new PHP feature, a shortcode for array() = [], i'll modify my answer so it will work for your older PHP version, also you were right I forgot to modify the data and use it as an array. Remember that you have to modify this code to work for you...

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you again for your help! ;) 
I'll try, but I have to study PHP/MySQL before... :/

Comment: Ehm...excuse me, I am in doubt about the voice "calendars" (INSERT INTO calendars, UPDATE calendars, etc.), do you mean that I have to create a table called "calendars" before the code? Because in this database there is already a table called "calendar", with "days" and other tables... Sorry, but I'm noob. :(

Comment: No I just assumed your table was called calendars. Just change it to the two tables you have that were that had the same structure.

Comment: Ok, so I can use table "calendars" that already exists... Because in my example I wrote "calendars" instead of the real db_name, but "calendars" is the name of a real table. :D  Thanks! ;)